# CM3 Two Camera Previews, one "hangs/freezes"

Tags: hardware, camera, picamera, compute-module-3

First time forum poster here, but I hit a wall in debugging this issue. Thank you in advance for any input!

Issue:
I am using two instances of raspistill preview for two hours on two Pi Cameras V2 which are attached to Cam 0/1 ports on the CM3. One of the two previews displayed, for varying amounts of time, simply stops working and "hangs/freezes." Both raspistill processes stay up for the allotted time, despite one of them being stuck on one frame. The earliest the the bug has appeared has been within 10 minutes. Sometimes it has even ran for 2 hours without hitting the issue. A lot of times it appears in the one hour mark.

Setup:
During debugging this I decided to start from scratch and see if I still ran into the issue. I definitely still ran into the issue, and here are the steps I took in setting up this CM3:
Brand new CM3
Raspbian Stretch with desktop on a 64 bit SD card
Followed these instructions to set up the cameras. I used the bts file on the bottom of this tutorial linked under "Enable Both Cameras" and followed the instructions to compile it to bt-boot.bin
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentati ... -camera.md
That's it! then I ran 2 instances of raspistill for two hours and the issue was still there.

What I need:
I need to display live feed from both cameras with them not spontaneously freezing. I discovered the problem writing python code using picamera. I simplified my python code to simply make two picameras, one for each port, and used start_preview for both of them, and this issue consistently appeared within 10 minutes. I was curious if I was going crazy or this issue still happened with raspistill previews, and it does.

What I've tried:
I've read through many forum posts on this sight that is in any way related to camera feed freezing. 
Not super savvy on going through logs trying to see if there's any issues popping up, but I do know:
1. The pi is not overheating
2. The pi is receiving enough Voltage
3. This is driving me crazy

I hope there is a simple fix to this, or maybe I am doing something blatantly wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer in the Raspberry Pi forums.  The camera experts are more likely to see the question.

Comment: Yea I thought so as well. I posted there first.